# How to add scrollbar to each <ul> in a nested <ul> list without breaking each <ul>'s position

Tags: jquery, css, nested, html-lists, css-position

I have a nested ul list like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>Subcat</a>
    <ul class="subcat">
      <li>
        <a>Subcat2</a>
        <ul class="subcat2">
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to make each ul have a scrollbar. 
After many days of trying to achieve this this is what i have:
https://jsfiddle.net/yaeqouem/3/

Just follow the "test here" links to see the result.

As you can see the scroll bar appears on the last child (the red ul), that works. 
But when i add overflow-y:auto or scroll to the middle ul (the blue one) it
breaks the position of the red ul.

I have tried with setting z-index and !important on the position on the red ul but no luck.

Is my problem possible to solve with css? or do i have to use JavaScript or something else

Any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE

[This is what im trying to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKaYZ.png)

Comment: Set a height to the inner `ul` and control the overflow with CSS. Try `overflow-y: scroll;`

Answer (score 1):

add overflow:auto to subcat class

```
//Child ul
.subcat {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  overflow:auto;

  //Does not work, hides red ul.
  //overflow-x: hidden;
  //overflow-y: auto;
 // z-index: 999;
}
```

kindly check following js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yaeqouem/5/

Comment: Thank you @RRR but I don't want the horizontal scrollbar to appear. I added a image to show what i'm after.

Comment: since you are using external jQuery files I was not able to understand that.. I tried to recreate the scenario I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @RRR your solution is great. However it does not quite solve my problem since i need each category item to load a different result. I will provide my code so you can see whats going on. Its a Jquery plugin I'm working on. https://jsfiddle.net/yrgtz8fc/3/
What happens is i have a JSON with the categories and their results. Then i get each category and its result and append them to a ul and li with the functions renderMenu, list_subcat and list_subcat2. 

If you have any advice on how to solve this I am very thankful, otherwise i believe your solution is the best answer.